# Tarballing system nodes

Tags: filesystem, tar, chroot

Say I'm tarballing a chroot. Would it be reasonable if it tried to tarball a system node, say, `/dev/zero`?
Or would this just be as stupid as it sounds, resulting in tar infinitely trying to find the end of the zeros so it could compress them?

Comment: What does "tarballing a chroot" even mean?

Comment: @fkraiem It mean taking the folder of a chroot and attempting to force it into a tarball.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tar` is reasonably smart. When told to archive special nodes like `/dev/{zero,urandom,...}`, it stores the Major and Minor device numbers (as used in `mknod` command) required to create those files:

```
$ tar cf foo.tar /dev/zero                  
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
$ tar tvf foo.tar         
crw-rw-rw- root/root       1,5 2016-12-25 13:06 dev/zero
$ tar xf foo.tar                            
tar: dev/zero: Cannot mknod: Operation not permitted
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

It also doesn't archive block devices directly. See [How to convince tar (etc.) to archive block device contents?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/151009/70524)